# $(window).width() won't update after pinch zoom (chrome IOS)

Tags: jquery, ios, jquery-ui, chrome-ios

I'm trying to align a div to the center using $(window).width().
on Windows this trick works well, as  $(window).width() changes when zooming the page.

However, When zooming the page on Chrome IOS, $(window).width() returns always the same value, causing the div to be aligned to center only when the page is not zoomed in (nor zoomed out)

any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: There are known bugs with getting the windows client- and outer width on IOS -> http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2012/03/windowouterwidt.html

Answer (score 1):

Window height doesn't change on zoom, otherwise all of your content would change too as it would trigger a resize event. You would need to find a way to detech what the scale of the zoom is. Say for example you zoom 2x, the correct integars for the calculations would be window height x 2, but I don't know a way currently to detect the viewport scale. Hopefully this answer might be a jumping off point for somebody wiser than I.

Comment: I've found this http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units - a way to set with css, or jQuery css, the height or whatever using viewport units. This might work.